# BottomSheet in flutter under the SystemNavigationBar

Tags: android, flutter

When updating flutter, bottomsheet hidden under the systemnavigationbar in android,
[image]

app should be like above image
but show below image

[image]

my code that show bottomsheet id here:

```html
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: appBarPages(widget.name, context),
        body: Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8, top: 8.0, bottom: 70),
          child: bodyContent(),
        ),
        bottomSheet: sendMessage());
  }

  Widget sendMessage() {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<VisibleNotifier>(
        create: (_) => VisibleNotifier(false),
        child: Consumer<VisibleNotifier>(builder: (_, provider, child) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, top: 5),
          
            child: Text('bottomSheet'),
          );
        }));
  }
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you include your code?

Comment: share my code,this code is right but when update flutter,I encountered this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `Scaffold` body with a `SafeArea` widget.